# ROS2 : SDF to URDF

Tags: ros, ros2, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question gets asked a lot. But no clear answer on a ROS2 solution it seems.

Is there any ROS2 tool to convert a sdf into a urdf ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366935/ros2-:-sdf-to-urdf/) by [Dawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/63613/dawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not quite an answer to the question, but in ROS 2 Rolling (which eventually will become Galactic) the package `sdformat_urdf` allows one to use SDFormat instead of URDF for a robot description in ROS (with some limitations): https://github.com/ros/sdformat_urdf . There are some examples here: https://github.com/sloretz/drake_ros2_demos/ (the examples also use Drake, but Drake isn't a requirement of sdformat_urdf).

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0